# JSON.NET deserialization seems to think 1000 is 1000.0 thus cause integer convertion error, why?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a key value pair of

```
"number": 100,
```

I have Class property destination for it via deserialization:

```
public int number { get; set; }
```

I convert it to a string:

```
string myJson = Json.ToString(); //Json of type{Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject}
```

When I look at the string, in VS debugger as a string, I see that it is

```
"number": 100.0
```

So when I :

```
var myOrder = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order>(myJson);
```

I get :

```
Input string '100.0' is not a valid integer. Path 'items[0].units.number', line 16, position 24.
```

When I view "myJson" in the debugger as Json it is correct, but when viewed as a string it shows as 100.0. Clearly there seems to be an issue with the "ToString" operation, or something else that I have missed.

Any advice really appreciated.

For now my workaround is to use the following as my destination:

```
public decimal number { get; set; }
```

EDIT

This is my code to produce the JObject:

```
        public async Task<JObject> GetResponseAsync(string endPoint)
    {
        var response = await MakeGetRequestAsync(endPoint);
        return await ParseResponseAsync(response);
    }

    private async Task<JObject> ParseResponseAsync(HttpResponseMessage response)
    {
        var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var json = JObject.Parse(content);
        return json;
    }
```

EDIT 2

The Json comes from a REST call from a 3rd party service.

EDIT 3

I did explicitly define the whole Json string as a string via @"{},using the call response from Postman, for the same call, as a test,  and this worked fine. It was when I used the REST call directly that it failed.

EDIT 4:

Original Json fragment:

```
        "units": {
            "number": 100,
            "numberUpdatedOn": "2018-11-21T00:00:00Z",
            "priceUpdatedOn": "2018-11-21T00:00:00Z",
            "price": {
                "currency": "GBP",
                "amount": "1000.0000"
            }
        },
```

EDIT 5.

I think I have found the problem. I had another look in Postman's response and found the "Raw" to show
    "units":{"number":100.0000," 
and "Pretty" to show 
    "units": {"number": 1000,"

Perhaps I am missing something, but this seems really confusing. I guess the "Raw" data indicates that the 3rd party is really sending through a decimal. Just checked the API documentation and there is no type documentation for this attribute, although the value seems like an integer, but actually it is a decimal. I guess the moral of the story is to check the "Raw" view.

EDit 6:

Postman "Raw" View of REST Call response:

```
"units"   {"number":100.0000,"numberUpdatedOn":"2018-11-21T00:00:00Z","priceUpdatedOn":"2018-11-21T00:00:00Z","price":{"currency":"GBP","amount":"1000.0000"}}
```

Postman "Pretty" View of REST Call response:

```
        "units": {
            "number": 100,
            "numberUpdatedOn": "2018-11-21T00:00:00Z",
            "priceUpdatedOn": "2018-11-21T00:00:00Z",
            "price": {
                "currency": "GBP",
                "amount": "1000.0000"
            }
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]` theres not enough code here.

Comment: Show how the JObject is populated before calling ToString

Comment: `new JProperty("asd", 100).ToString()` produces `"asd": 100`. Your problem is on the serialization side.

Comment: Thanks all. Edit made. Json comes from REST call, so I am not serializing it, just trying to put it into an object.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem based on what is currently provided in the question. Did this as a test and context matches as expected        `[Test]
        public void MyTestMethod() {
            var content = "{\"number\":100}";
            var json = JObject.Parse(content);
            var s = json.ToString();
        }`

Comment: Q: Could you show us an example of the raw JSON you're trying to deserialize?  Are you *sure* the JSON doesn't have "100.0"?  Q: At the end of the day, is using "decimal" instead of "int" a viable workaround?  Especially if you can't control the JSON?

Comment: Thanks all. I can use decimal, but wanted to understand why this error was creeping in. Thanks Nkosi for your test. Useful. I will try.

Comment: Original Json is posted as Edit.

Comment: @SamJolly knew it had to be something external. :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you convert the JObject directly to the class you want?

```
var myOrder = Json.ToObject<Order>();
```

I think the issue you are encountering is due to `JObject.ToString()`. I wouldn't trust that to give you the same JSON string as might have been provided from the 3rd party. Though according to the documentation I would expect `"number": 100` to be preserved through `.ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks for this. See Edit 5. I think I have found the cause.

Comment: Moral of story is to check the "Raw" Response view in Postman, I guess...